# Can not get the value of AsyncStorage on redux intial state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying so hard to get the value of a key I stored in `AsyncStorage` in the `React native` app that I am working on to be set as the value of the initialState of the redux toolkit store.
I have used some methods mentioned here but I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my code:

```
const initialState={
sessions: null
}

export const logInUsers = createAsyncThunk('userme', async(name, thunkAPI)=>{

const {user_username, user_password} = name
 try {

const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('sessionId')
console.log(value, 'my value')
if(value !== null) {
  return value
}
} catch (error) {
console.log(err.response.data)
return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data)
}

})
 
 const sessionSlice = createSlice({
name: 'session',
initialState,

extraReducers: (builders)=>{
   builders.addCase(logInUsers.fulfilled, (state, {payload})=>{
    state.sessionLoading = false
        state.sessions = payload;
       
    })
 
   }
  })
```

The store.js

```
export const Store = configureStore({

  reducer: {
    session: sessionSlice
  },

 })
```

The component where I used it:

```
 const LogoPage = ()=>{
    const didAttempt = useSelector(state => state.session.sessions !== null);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!didAttempt){
        dispatch(logInUsers({user_username: 'King', user_password: 'king'}))
    }      
  
   }, [])
```

I read that I could do this with `redux persist`. I am seeking for a way to do this without using redux persist. Is this possible? The above code was gotten from this site as an answer to the same question. It is not working for me.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean you get an error message?

Comment: It is working now, I was making a mistake